# How to remove a specific clone created with javascript in html when a button is pressed inside that cloned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code I have created clones a div section when I press the "Add Co-Pi" btn. Inside my clone creator function (JS) I specify the id's I want for each clone to have.

I have now added a delete button inside the div in order to eliminate the cloned div in which the button finds it self in. Problem is, I can't seem to find how to obtain the div id in which all my elements are inside at the moment of pressing the delete button. I know I can manually type the div name and send it as a parameter to the delete function, but, I want the delete button to automatically extract the div id and send it to the delete function.

I know I might not be explaining myself properly, I am new at using javascript and html.

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code. I am using php, html, javascript and sql.

html:

---

```
 <div id="dynamicInputCoPi">


<!-- <select id='Co_PI_Query' name='Co_PI_Query' onClick= "showId(this.id);">   -->
<select id='Co_PI_Query' name='Co_PI_Query' onClick="copiSelection(1);">    
<?php    
//This code shows all the selected values from the co-pi table and displays them in a dropdown menu.
//The value is selected by the idCoPI   
//First Query //Select * could be changed to select specified data to be shwn
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM co_pi_table
          ";


/**       */
//Checks to see if query is successful        
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);                  
if($result == false){
    die ('<br>Error in Query to CoPI Database Table : ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
<option value="">**Click here to select Co-PI**</option>
<?php

//echo "I am here";
//Start While
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?> 
<!-- Options inside the DropMenu will be populated by the query -->
<option value=" <?php echo $row['idCoPI'];?> ">
 <?php //echo $row['idCoPI'] . " | " . $row['Fname'] . "-" . $row['Lname'];
  echo $row['Fname'] . ", " . $row['Lname'] . "-" . $row['SLname'];
 ?>
</option>
<?php
 } //End of While
 ?>  
</select>         

<input type="button" value="+ Add Co-Pi" onClick="openCoPiWin();"> 

 <input type="button" id="Reload_Query" value="Refresh Query" onClick="reloadQuery();">
 <br>

 <!--
 <input type="button" id="Add_Query" value="Select another Co-Pi" onClick="duplicateDivSection(dynamicInputCoPi);">
  -->
  <input type="button" id="Add_Query" value="Select another Co-Pi" onClick="duplicateDivSection();">
  <br>  
  <input type="button" id="Delete_Query" value="Delete this selection" onClick="deleteClone(document.getElementById('dynamicInputCoPi1'));">
  <br>
</div>
</div>
```

---

Javascript:

---

```
//This function adds another Co-PI dropdown menu to select from when button "Add" is pressed
//document.getElementById('Add_Query').onclick = duplicateDivSection;

    var counter = 1;
    //var limite = 5;
    //var original = document.getElementById('dynamicInputCoPi');


function duplicateDivSection(){
    document.getElementById('Add_Query').onclick = duplicateDivSection;
    //var counter = 1;
    var limite = 5; //Final dynamicInputCoPi value will be "dynamicInputCoPi4"
    var original = document.getElementById('dynamicInputCoPi');


    //var original = document.getElementById(divName);
    if (counter == limite)  { //Final dynamicInputCoPi value will be "dynamicInputCoPi4"
          //alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + i + " Co-PI or Co-Investigators");
          var return_Function = return_coPiCounting();

          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " Co-PI or Co-Investigators.\n" + "Amount of total coPi entered is: " + return_Function );
     }
     else {
            var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone. "true" means clone all childNodes and all event handlers
                //clone.id = divName + counter;
                //clone.id = divName + (i);
                clone.id = "dynamicInputCoPi" + (counter); //This id will become "dynamicInputCoPi1" the first time it runs
                // or clone.id = ""; if the divs don't need an ID
                clone.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].id = "Co_PI_Query" + counter; //Changes id of clone
                clone.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].name = "Co_PI_Query" + counter; //Changes name of clone
                clone.append('<input type="button" value="Delete Co-PI" name="Delete_CoPI">'); //Adds another button to delete form selection
                original.parentNode.appendChild(clone); //appends all changes to new clone
                //i++;
             //counter = counter + 1;
             counter++;
            coPiCounting(counter);
            return false;
     }
}
//*******************************************************************************************************************



//Deletes last co-pi selection 
function deleteClone(toDelete){
    $(toDelete).remove();
    //counter--;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener on the clones delete button as you create it. When the deleteClone function is called, `this` will refer to the `input` that was clicked. From that `input` reference we can get the parent (which is the `div` of that clone) and remove it- you don't even need the div id.

Here is an example that uses `createElement` to create the delete button and add the event listener to it.

```js
var original = document.getElementById("dynamicInputCoPi");

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  cloneOriginal(i);
}

function cloneOriginal(counter) {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "dynamicInputCoPi" + counter;
  
  clone.appendChild(createDeleteButton(counter));
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  counter++;
}

function deleteClone() {
  this.parentNode.remove();
}

function createDeleteButton(counter) {
  var deleteElem = document.createElement("input");
  deleteElem.type = "button";
  deleteElem.value = "Delete Co-PI " + counter;
  deleteElem.name = "Delete_CoPI";
  deleteElem.addEventListener("click", deleteClone);
  return deleteElem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="dynamicInputCoPi">
    <p> hello </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Adnelon1 glad I could help!